# Codeception4: GroupManager reports missing test file

Tags: php, symfony, codeception, symfony5

I upgraded **Codeception** to v4 (according to [THIS](https://codeception.com/12-18-2019/codeception-4.html)) and then **Symfony** to v5 (according to [THIS](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/upgrade_major.html)). Now, when I try to run tests I get an error about missing test file:

> > root@blabla: vendor/bin/codecept run
> >
> > In GroupManager.php line 129:
> >
> > GroupManager: File or directory /var/www/html/tests/unit/SomeFileCest.php does not exist

This file does **NOT** exist in current branch. It exists in another branch of the project, but current should not know anything about this file!

This problem happens no matter which branch I switch to. So somehow `Codeception` remembers, that one branch has additional test and demands that test in other branches. Looks like some sort of `cache`.

If I switch to the branch **WITH the missing file**, everything looks OK (I do get an error, but because of the old framework expected).

Error appears if I do `vendor/bin/codecept run` or `vendor/bin/codecept run tests/functional` for example (note that the missing test is a **unit** test).

I tried deleting `/var` and `/vendor` and running `composer install/update`. I also tried removing the branch completely and pulling from remote, but no joy.

Anybody has any idea why this would happen and how to fix this?

Comment: The file was referred to by some group configuration, most likely by `tests/_support/failed`.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

**EDIT:**
After some simple testing it looks like it's related to old references in `tests/_support/failed` (as @Naktibalda mentioned in his/her comment).

---

I still don't fully understand what happened, but this can be fixed by running:

```
vendor/bin/codecept clean
```

From `Codeception` help:

> > clean                 Recursively cleans log and generated code

I will try to investigate further to understand why this happens, but for now this is what I have.

I hope this helps someone avoid the frustrations I went through ;)

Comment: Yup still works to solve the problem! Still no idea what the problem is. 8/2020 still get the issue latest versions, acceptance test, WordPress Codeception.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this answer. I figured that there might be some kind of cache/generated code happening, but wasn't sure. Having such a quick win as finding this answer really helped me out!

Comment: Worked, thank you!  Is the path correct by the way? On linux I used `./vendor/bin/codecept`

Comment: @funder7 It depends on your setup and which directory you are running it from. In my case (docker container) I was in the main project directory, where `vendor` lives. But if you have different setup or run it not from main directory, then perhaps you need to adjust.

Comment: @callmebob I'm using a docker container, with php & composer, I run every command from the project root!

Answer (score 0):

For my case we were using paracept, to run stuff in parallel. This generated group files in `/tests/_data`

Once I removed the group files in this folder my test suite ran normally.

Worth noting that `codecept clean` doesn't clear this `_data` folder.